# Post for Stack Exchange API

Tags: app, c#

**Screenshot / Code Snippet**

As an internal enterprise code , this will not be available to the public.

**About**

Our application is a Microsoft Internal application used for internal purposes.

**License**

Not applicable. Our application is a Microsoft Internal application.

**Download**

As a Microsoft internal application this app will only be available to internal employees only.

**Platform**

Microsoft Edge/ Google Chrome

**Contact**

Microsoft Corp

**Code**

This code is Microsoft internal and is built with C# and will not be available to the public for use.